# Out of memory exception with Collections

Tags: java

Here is my requirement. It throws out of memory exception and  GC overhead limit exceeded exception. Please advice the best way to implement this.

```
 public static List<Consumer> retrieve(){ 
   List<Consumer> consumers = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
      Consumer consumer = new Consumer();
      consumer.setAge(new Integer(i));
      consumer.setBirthDate(new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy").parse("01061986"));
      consumer.setName("Consumer" + new String(new Integer(i).toString()));
      consumers.add(consumer);
    }
    return consumers;
  }
```

Comment: Not enough information. How do you use this method?

Comment: You're creating several different objects in each of the 100000 iterations of the loop. It doesn't help that you're using a ridiculous method to convert an `int` to a `String` - use `Integer.toString(i)` instead of the convoluted `new String(new Integer(i).toString())`. You also use the deprecated `Integer` constructor instead of `Integer.valueOf()` which may save on object creation. Even without that, though, you are creating 100000 `Consumer` objects each with at least 3 fields which are also `Object`s. All this data isn't going to fit in a variable (in memory) when you've got 50MB of space.

Comment: What do you do with the return value of this method?  What other code are you running?

Comment: I am calling this java code in TIBCO Bw process. On the other side I need to read the objects created and clear the memory.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: Hi Manuel, I have reread your question. We need more information about your problem for sure. What are you doing with the created Consumer instances? You have to make sure you remove any references to them quickly so that the GC can get rid of them. Still, don't know if 1 sec is enough.

Please add more info. I'm leaving my previous answer in case you find it useful. :-)

---

From the code you posted, I can tell you that it runs successfully on my computer using a 50MB heap size. I'm pretty sure you have more code if 50MB is not enough on your computer.

You can start performing some optimizations to the given function. I would begin by removing some instantiations and castings. Take a look at the following first approach:

```
public static Consumer[] retrieve() throws ParseException{
    final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");
    final int MAX = 100000;
    final Consumer[] consumers = new Consumer[MAX];

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
      Consumer consumer = new Consumer();
      consumer.setAge(i);
      consumer.setBirthDate(sdf.parse("01061986"));
      consumer.setName("Consumer" + i);
      consumers[i] = consumer;
    }

    return consumers;
}
```

Some of the changes to the rest of your code must take in consideration that:

- age in Consumer class is defined as `int` which is a primitive instead of `Integer` which is a class.
- We are returning an array, instead of a `List`

With the code you're providing I'm getting the following memory info:

```
Free memory before (bytes): 50331648
Free memory after  (bytes): 24865408
```

With the code changes I'm providing it changes to:

```
Free memory before (bytes): 50331648
Free memory after  (bytes): 33736624
```

You can see an important change in memory consumption.

If you are interested about how to check the free memory in the JVM take a look at: `Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()`.

Finally, I must say that it is important that you add more information to help you get a better answer.

Comment: @Andres I had calculation, 500B/instance of quite simple class cannot say "is impossible" , so "maybe is possible after optimisation". Congratulation for efficient code

Comment: Hi Andres, I am reading the created object in an another class and clear the memory.

Comment: Hi Manuel, could you please add to your question the function that reads the data and the code you're using for running them every second as well? I may be wrong, but I'm guessing you want to implement a producers/consumers example. Thanks.

Comment: Also, if you have a constant date, you can add a line before the for loop like  `final Date date = sdf.parse("01061986");` and just reference it inside the loop using  `consumer.setBirthDate(date);` lowering your memory consumption even more.

Comment: Hi Andres, below is the code to read the created object and clear the memory. Please advice                                                                                                         public static boolean readMethod (){
   Iterator<Customer> itrCustomer = customers.iterator();
  while (itrCustomer.hasNext()){
   System.out.println(itrCustomer.next().getName());
  }
  itrCustomer=null;
  System.gc();
  return true;
 }

Comment: Andres, the method is called from TIBCO timer process which is scheduled at every one second.

Comment: Andres, you are correct. This follows producer and consumer pattern.

Comment: Yup, that is helpful to contextualize your problem. The code provided for reading the items may not have enough time to print all the items before the consumer creates more items. The best approach is to use threads and some kind of synchronization method. There are some examples on the web like this one http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2015/07/how-to-use-wait-notify-and-notifyall-in.html which uses wait and notify. I can help you with it tomorrow. Please follow me on twitter where we can interact using pm's. My user is ajaimesv. Best.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `Stream<Consumer>` or `Iterator<Consumer>` as a return type and also modify the other part that calls this method to do so. It is impossible to return a `List<Consumer>` which will contain all 100,000 object instances with only 50MB.

Converting your example method to `Stream<Consumer>` version:

```
public static Stream<Consumer> retrieve() {
    return Stream.iterate(
            new Consumer(0), 
            lastConsumer -> new Consumer(lastConsumer.getAge() + 1)
        .limit(100000);
}
```

And change your Consumer constructor to initialize all the variables instead.

```
public Consumer(int age)
{
    this.setAge(age);
    consumer.setBirthDate(new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy").parse("01061986"));
    consumer.setName("Consumer" + age);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Alex, I completely agree with you it is impossible to hold 100,000 object instances with only 50MB. There is an another part of scheduler runs which will clear the memory by reading.